# sorting a csv file with 3 columns

Tags: command-line, csv, sort

I am trying to sort a csv file containing 3 values. The first one is the one that matters. It contains many times the number 1, 2, 3, 4 etc etc. But each number doesnt appear the same number of times as the other number. So, i wanna sort the csv file from its 1st column, from less times of appearance of each number to the highest number of appearces.

for example - i dont mention the 2nd and 3rd row because i want it sorted via the 1st column

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
3
4
4

->

3
4
4
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
```

using mac but i can get access to a linux

here is the file: http://www.mediafire.com/file/v0azlrb3sx9r5x7/example.csv/file

Comment: you should provide the full csv

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/v0azlrb3sx9r5x7/example.csv/file

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR{s[$1]++} NR>FNR{print s[$1],$0}' csvfile csvfile \
| sort -n | cut -d, -f2-
```

- `awk` will count number of occurrences of first field (`s[$1]++`) and then adds it (`print s[$1],$0` to the rows). (Note, that `awk` needs to read the file twice).
- `sort -n` will sort the result
- `cut -d, -f2-` will remove the number again.

Comment: didnt work. the sorting gets messed up

Comment: it works fine with the example provided. Please see my comment on your question.

Comment: just uploaded it to mediafire.

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) you can apply this command to your TSV

```
mlr --tsv count-similar -g type -o count then sort -n count ./example.csv >./output.tsv
```

to have something like

```
+------+-------+-----------+-------+
| type | value | condition | count |
+------+-------+-----------+-------+
| 66   | 0     | hela      | 2     |
| 66   | 0     | hela      | 2     |
| 23   | 1     | hela      | 6     |
| 23   | 1     | hela      | 6     |
| 23   | 1     | hela      | 6     |
| 23   | 1     | hela      | 6     |
| 23   | 1     | hela      | 6     |
| 23   | 1     | hela      | 6     |
| 27   | 1     | hela      | 9     |
| 27   | 1     | hela      | 9     |
| 27   | 1     | hela      | 9     |
| 27   | 1     | hela      | 9     |
| 27   | 1     | hela      | 9     |
| 27   | 1     | hela      | 9     |
| 27   | 1     | hela      | 9     |
| 27   | 1     | hela      | 9     |
| 27   | 1     | hela      | 9     |
| 34   | 0     | hela      | 9     |
| 34   | 0     | hela      | 9     |
| 34   | 0     | hela      | 9     |
| 34   | 0     | hela      | 9     |
| 34   | 0     | hela      | 9     |
| 34   | 0     | hela      | 9     |
| 34   | 0     | hela      | 9     |
| 34   | 0     | hela      | 9     |
| 34   | 0     | hela      | 9     |
| 2    | 0     | hela      | 14    |
| 2    | 0     | hela      | 14    |
| 2    | 0     | hela      | 14    |
| 2    | 0     | hela      | 14    |
| ..   | ..    | ..        | ..    |
```

- `count-similar -g type` to count and group by `type`;
- `-o count` to set the output count field;
- `sort -n count` to sort by `count` field.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from writing those amazing queries, another way of sorting the columns of CSV files is to utilize a Relational Database Management System(RDBMS), such as [Acho](https://acho.io/).

1. **Upload your CSV as a Resource**

   You can upload your CSV file using Single CSV or Multiple CSV. Please note that all the column names, column data types, and the number of columns need to be the same if you are uploading multiple CSV files as MCSV.

   If the CSV upload is not successful, then just try out the *Safe mode*, it can automatically turn all the columns into *String* data type.
2. **Add the resource into a project**

   After uploading the CSV, just add the CSV file into a project, and go to the workspace to view the table. In order to sort the column, you can simply click the *Sort* button under *Column Dropdown* to sort the column you need.

The GUI is easy to understand and maneuver.

[image]